# How do I space between the top row and the bottom row in the footnote

Tags: footnotes

I'm writing an article. How can I leave a space between the footnote and the object above. Thank's.

You can find all the necessary files at [this link.](https://easyupload.io/m/zs2cok)
[image: Footnote and other object]

```
\documentclass{elektr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{xy,xypic}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{eufrak,amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,eurosym,enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref,multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\yil{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}

\title{Synthesizing a robust proactive model}

\author[AUTHOR and AUTHOR]{
    \textbf{John Doe\thanks{john@blablabla.com}~}\\
    Department of Computer Engineering, Turkey, \\ ORCID iD: https://orcid.org/
    \\ [1.8em]
    
    \rec{.201}
    \acc{.201}
    \finv{..201}
}
\input{elksty.tex}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
            \begin{abstract}Mobile phones are the most common personal vehicles used for communication in the world. The most common type of written communication other than voice calls on mobile phones is SMS (short message service)....
        
        \keywords{data mining, machine learning}
    \end{abstract}
        \section{Introduction}
    \label{Int}
         Mobile devices, particularly smart phones, are being used at an increasing level by users due to various functions they provide  According to the data obtained by Statistica \footnote{Number of smartphone users worldwide 2016-2021. Website \url{https://www.statista.com/statistics/330695/number-of-smartphone-users-worldwide/} [Accessed December 25, 2018]}  the SMS traffic increased to 8.3 trillion in 2015 from over 5 trillion in 2009. 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There is, with most document classes, a space in this situation, so we don't have enough information to be able to help you.  Please add a small, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.  Then a potential helper can copy and paste it for experimentation, and likely a quick answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tried to prepare everything as you indicated. Thank you for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `\thanks` by the package does not leave enough space for a footnote. But, even solving that, for example using `\thanks{john@blablabla.com \medskip}`, there is a conflict between `lineno` and the footnotes.

Both issues of your MWE can by solved adding the package `bigfoot`.

[image: a]

This is the code. Please note the comments.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{elektr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,a
    citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{xy,xypic}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{eufrak,amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,eurosym,enumerate}  %% The eufrak package is redundant if the amsfonts package i used <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref,multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{bigfoot} % added <<<<<<<
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\yil{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}

\title{Synthesizing a robust proactive model}

\author[AUTHOR and AUTHOR]{%
    \textbf{John Doe\thanks{john@blablabla.com}}
    Department of Computer Engineering, Turkey, \\ ORCID iD: https://orcid.org/
    \\ [1.8em]
    
    \rec{.201}
    \acc{.201}
    \finv{..201}
}

\input{elksty.tex}  % many warning in compilation <<<<<<<<<<

\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{document}    
    \maketitle  

\begin{abstract}Mobile phones are the most common personal vehicles used for communication in the world. The most common type of written communication other than voice calls on mobile phones is SMS (short message service)....

\keywords{data mining, machine learning}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{Int}

Mobile devices, particularly smart phones, are being used at an increasing level by users due to various functions they provide  According to the data obtained
by Statistica \footnote{Number of smartphone users worldwide 2016-2021. \\ % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
Website \url{https://www.statista.com/statistics/330695/number-of-smartphone-users-worldwide/} [Accessed December 25, 2018]}  the SMS traffic increased to 8.3 trillion in 2015 from over 5 trillion in 2009. 

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
used as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical
reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical
reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would
thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the
Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.
Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.
Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic
unity. There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are
what first give rise to human reason.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

what us the purpose of these

```
\yil{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What you wrote is not an answer.